# Scroll on Button Click in Elementor Not working

Tags: wordpress, elementor

## Basically what i want to do is when i click on the buy now it should scroll down to the section below, after watching many videos i've figured it out how to do it but the problem is because i have made the button position fixed ,offset -104 it is not working

i have tried giving position absolute but the same problem occurs it only works(scroll on click) with the default position but then the layout gets distorted [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCDV7.png)